# Php 7.1 + Pecl-event + libevent - is hanging in weird case

Tags: asynchronous, libevent, php-7.1, reactphp, pecl-event

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471649/centos-6-php7-1-libevent-nginx-returns-502/47518006#47518006), I've switched to [pecl-event](https://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=event&version=2.3.0) library. Now I have:

```
[root]# php -v
PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2017 08:40:02) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologieswith Zend OPcache v7.1.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies 
[root]# php --info | grep event
/etc/php.d/event.ini event libevent2 headers version => 2.1.8-stable
[root]# pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package Version State
event   2.3.0   stable
```

The example below behaves strangely. If `$loop->run()` is called from within of `runme()` function, it works and callback is called. But if `$loop->run()` is called from outside of `runme()`, it hangs!

```php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$inner = count($argv) > 1;

$loop = new \React\EventLoop\ExtEventLoop();
//$loop = new \React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop();

runme($loop, $inner);

if (!$inner) {
    echo "Outer start\n";
    $loop->run();
}

function runme(\React\EventLoop\LoopInterface $loop, $inner)
{
    $contextOpts = [];
    $flags = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT;
    $context = stream_context_create($contextOpts);
    $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://127.0.0.1:3306', $errno, $errstr, 0, $flags, $context);
    stream_set_blocking($socket, 0);

    $loop->addWriteStream($socket, function ($socket) use ($loop) {
        echo "done  ".(false === stream_socket_get_name($socket, true) ? 'false' : 'true')."\n";
        $loop->removeWriteStream($socket);
    });

    if ($inner) {
        echo "Inner start\n";
        $loop->run();
    }

    echo "Exit runme\n";
}
```

Run results:

```
[root@vultr Scraper]# php ./tests/test.php --inner
Inner start
done  false
Exit runme
[root@vultr Scraper]# php ./tests/test.php 
Exit runme
Outer start
...............HANGING HERE...........
```

Do I miss something or is it an issue with one of the libraries/PHP? Does anybody have experience in running php7.1 + react + libevent?

UPDATE: ====================================================================

I did test with latest "react/socket" library "0.8.6".

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$inner = count($argv) > 1;

$loop = new \React\EventLoop\ExtEventLoop();

$connector = new React\Socket\Connector($loop);

runme($loop, $connector, $inner);

if (!$inner) {
    echo "Outer start\n";
    $loop->run();
}

function runme(\React\EventLoop\LoopInterface $loop, React\Socket\Connector $connector, $inner)
{
    $connector->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3306')->
    then(function (\React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        echo ("Hello MySQL!\n");
        $conn->close();
    },function ($e) {
        echo ("Bye MySQL!\n");
    })->done();

    if ($inner) {
        echo "Inner start\n";
        $loop->run();
    }

    echo "Exit runme\n";
}
```

it works proper and returns:

```
$ php ./testMysql.php 
Exit runme
Outer start
Hello MySQL!
$ php ./testMysql.php  --inner
Inner start
Hello MySQL!
Exit runme
```

But if you go into \React\Socket\TcpConnector::waitForStreamOnce() and remove $canceller function in new Promise object like below, than it hangs again. Looks like it works in latest version of react a kind of accidentally  as socket not stored obvious way, and in fact similar to code in v0.4.6.

```
private function waitForStreamOnce($stream)
    {
        $loop = $this->loop;

        return new Promise\Promise(function ($resolve, $reject) use ($loop, $stream) {
            $loop->addWriteStream($stream, function ($stream) use ($loop, $resolve, $reject) {
                $loop->removeWriteStream($stream);

                // The following hack looks like the only way to
                // detect connection refused errors with PHP's stream sockets.
                if (false === stream_socket_get_name($stream, true)) {
                    fclose($stream);

                    $reject(new \RuntimeException('Connection refused'));
                } else {
                    $resolve(new Connection($stream, $loop));
                }
            });
        });
    }



$ php ./testMysql.php  --inner
Inner start
.....HANGING
$ php ./testMysql.php 
Exit runme
Outer start
...HANGING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the ***`$socket`** variable gets **destroyed*** when `runme()` returns (just as any local PHP variable!). As a result, the **connection** opened on this socket **is closed**.

Event extension makes its best to prevent memory leaks, so it does not store references to the user variables if possible. Particularly, all methods accepting a [socket resource](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.resources.php) ([`Event::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/event.construct.php), for instance) only [retrieve](https://bitbucket.org/osmanov/pecl-event/src/05ce10baf0061dd58ae3b13cb06eb63ded190da0/php7/src/util.c?fileviewer=file-view-default#util.c-28:28) the underlying numeric file descriptor from the input variables. The ***user is** actually **responsible for keeping** those **variables alive***.

The following script fixes the issue by moving `$socket` to the global scope.

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$inner = count($argv) > 1;
$loop = new \React\EventLoop\ExtEventLoop();
$socket = init_socket();

runme($loop, $socket, $inner);

if (!$inner) {
    echo "Outer start\n";
    $loop->run();
}

function init_socket()
{
    $contextOpts = [];
    $flags = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT;
    $context = stream_context_create($contextOpts);
    $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://test.local:80', $errno, $errstr, 0, $flags, $context);
    stream_set_blocking($socket, 0);
    return $socket;
}

function runme(\React\EventLoop\LoopInterface $loop, $socket, $inner)
{
    $loop->addWriteStream($socket, function ($socket) use ($loop) {
        echo "done  ".(false === stream_socket_get_name($socket, true) ? 'false' : 'true')."\n";
        $loop->removeWriteStream($socket);
    });

    if ($inner) {
        echo "Inner start\n";
        $loop->run();
    }

    echo "Exit runme\n";
}
```

In a real application you would probably store `$socket` as a class member variable.

Comment: As I wrote this code is part of react/socket-client library v0.4.6 which works fine in php5.6 . So seems I have to find update this library in my application.

Comment: @DmitryPismennyy, even if the script worked as expected on PHP 5.6, it was just because of the GC behavior which considered to not destroy `$socket`. I have described the root of the problem: _the `$socket` variable must be preserved(!); otherwise, the connection will be lost, and the loop will behave unpredictably (it may hang, or it may segfault... what would you expect from the program if it operates on a closed file descriptor?)_. The idea applies to PHP 7 as well.

Comment: I do not mean update about working code in PHP 5.6. I meant update in my main post according latest react library that work properly by accidentally at first glance.

Comment: @DmitryPismennyy, the second part of your question looks like entirely different question, as you are beginning to use React connectors instead of explicit sockets. Besides, it is not very clear how the underlying stream is created, how it is passed to the Event extension, and when it gets destroyed. In order to figure out answers to these questions one needs to make some serious debugging for different versions of React. And this, I'm afraid, goes slightly beyond the scope of SO. I would rather address the second part of the question to React devs, in their bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Hey ReactPHP core developer here, just looked into your script and I can reproduce this locally so I'm going to file an issue (even though this might be out of our scope) for this.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$inner = count($argv) > 1;

$loop = new \React\EventLoop\ExtEventLoop();
//$loop = new \React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop();

runme($loop, $inner);

    $contextOpts = [];
    $flags = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT;
    $context = stream_context_create($contextOpts);
    $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://127.0.0.1:3306', $errno, $errstr, 0, $flags, $context);
    stream_set_blocking($socket, 0);

    $loop->addWriteStream($socket, function ($socket) use ($loop) {
        echo "done  ".(false === stream_socket_get_name($socket, true) ? 'false' : 'true')."\n";
        $loop->removeWriteStream($socket);
    });

    if ($inner) {
        echo "Inner start\n";
        $loop->run();
    }

    echo "Exit runme\n";
```

But alternatively I suggest you look into our [socket component](https://reactphp.org/socket/#client-usage) for handling connections.

Which could look something like:

```
$loop = new \React\EventLoop\ExtEventLoop();
$connector = new React\Socket\Connector($loop);

$connector->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3306')->then(function (ConnectionInterface $conn) use ($loop) {
    $conn->write("Hello MySQL!\n");
});

$loop->run();
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Actually, I\ve extracted above code from application that uses react + react/mysql library, which is based on \React\SocketClient\Connector(). Application works fine with php5.6 + libevent 2.0. But after upgrading to php7.1 I can't combine workable solution with event libraries.

Comment: This is a very common issue with asynchronous programming and with Event extension in particular. The users usually do not realize that the extension does not keep references to the input variables which are used to configure the events. (The `$data` parameter is special.) From the user's perspective, it might look convenient to only pass a socket to some event constructor and then forget about it. However, this behavior would also require the user to free the references when they are no longer needed. And the latter scenario makes asynchronous programming even more difficult, in my opinion.

Comment: As I wrote this code is part of react/socket-client library v0.4.6 which works fine in php5.6 . So seems I have to update library.